# What are the "strong" beats in a 16th note funk groove?

Tags: composition

In classical music there is this term of strong and weak beats or "accented" beats. In 4/4 time this would normally be on the quarter notes... so there would be 4 strong beats a bar but I was wondering how this changes when you have a syncopated groove like a funk bassline. Do composers use the 16th note subdivisions in a bar as accented beats?

My question is with regards to dissonant passing tones in counterpoint. Usually in CP the dissonant notes happen on the weak beats and I am studying dissonant passing tones so I wanted to apply this knowledge to a more modern genre like funk or pop

Comment: Many, many different ways!

Comment: Take it from the master, himself. https://youtu.be/IHE6hZU72A4 According to Bootsy, just keep it on the one, and you can do anything else you want with it. “And that’s the funk.” Interesting to hear him vocally grunt the “ands” whether his notes are on them or not. Funk is a feeling.

Comment: I’d suggest a literature review to help you understand how off beat accents are a part of funk. Lesson 1: “Superbad” (James Brown). Lesson 2: “Mother Popcorn” (James Brown), etc

Comment: Classically, there is one strong beat in 4/4, the first one. Nitpicking terminology aside, you're not going to be able to do this by blindly following rules, because the classical conception of metre is fundamentally different from modern ideas about metre. You're going to need to understand the mindset behind this "only on the offbeats" treatment of dissonance and translate that understanding to funk, rather than naively placing common practice counterpoint on top of a funk groove. This is a cross-cultural translation which will involve subjective judgement calls.

Comment: Esther.. I hear you but lets say that I gave mozart a CF with a syncopated bassline. Surely, he would have used the theory he knew to compose CP to that bassline. So my question is valid even though you are right that they are two completely different styles.

Answer (score 3):

The beats in 4/4 are quarter notes, 1, 2, 3, 4, while accents may be shifted with respect to them. If you move the beats themselves, then the rhythm is no longer syncopated and you end up with a compound meter, which is not what normally happens in funk music.

> Usually in CP the dissonant notes happen on the weak beats

Does this sentence take into account syncopation? I would say whatever applies to "strong beats" in such description must apply for syncopated notes as well.

In jazz and deriving styles it is more complicated because they much more open for dissonant notes than classical or baroque music, but also because the notes on weak parts of the bar are often accented, which doesn't necessarily imply syncopation.

Comment: THank you. I understand what you said about there being more dissonance but I want to compose a piece of music using counterpoint as a technique. I wanted to know whether I should use the syncopated bass notes as the "strong beats" as instructed in counterpoint. This is just an exercise because up until now my teacher has only given me straight quarter note Cantus Firmus and I wanted to have a CF that has a bass line that is syncopated. Make sense?

Comment: @armani If the bass line is syncopated then the accents are _shifted_ from strong beats to weak beats, meaning what you would play on a strong beat, is played on a weak beat instead.

Comment: so then correct me if I am wrong but then it is bassline that defines the strong or weak metric positions in a bar right?

Comment: @armani I'm not sure if I understand. Beats are the main metric accents, and in a typical, syncopated or not, funk song they are at each quarter note in the bar.